# ¿Es posible saber si mi dispositivo Android esta liberado?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy realizando una aplicación android y uno de los requerimientos es saber si el dispositivo esta debloquedo, he revisado algunas clases como TelephonyManager pero solo me indica el nombre del carrier

¿Es posible saber a través de código si un dispositivo Android esta liberado?

Saludos.

Comment: Has intentado con un dispositivo que no sea liberado y la clase te devuelve el nombre del carrier?

Answer (score 0):

Existen métodos para verificar si tu device esta  liberado o no, pero estos métodos tienen falsos positivos con algunos devices. Pero google tiene una API, llamada **SafetyNet Attestation API** pero igual tienes algunos falsos, positivos, pero es lo que mejor se tiene para capturar si un device esta liberado, generalmente se utiliza esta API para verificar la seguridad de instalación de nuestra app.

Referencia : https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html

```
private void callSafetyNetAttentationApi() {
    SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest(generateNonce(), SAFETY_NET_CHECK_API_KEY)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this,
            response -> {
                // Usar response.getJwsResult() para obtener el resultado.
                String jwsResponse = decodeJws(response.getJwsResult());
                try {
                    JSONObject attestationResponse = new JSONObject(jwsResponse);
                    boolean ctsProfileMatch = attestationResponse.getBoolean("ctsProfileMatch");
                    boolean basicIntegrity = attestationResponse.getBoolean("basicIntegrity");
                    if (!ctsProfileMatch || !basicIntegrity) {
                        // Esto indica que el device esta liberado/ manipulado
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // json exception
                }
            })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
            // Un error ocurrió cuando te estabas comunicando con el servidor.
        });
}
```

El parámetro `SAFETY_NET_CHECK_API_KEY` es un KEY que tienes que generar. Lo puedes hacer siguiendo -> https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation#obtain-api-key

Espero te ayude :)